# JSON is showing Object rather than numerical value in output

Tags: javascript, json, object, visual-studio-code, web-development-server

When I am executing the URL in Chrome, I am getting this below as output:

```
{
  "Train_score": {
    "0": 0.9892473118
  },
  "Test_score": {
    "0": 0.9831932773
  }
}
```

But, when I am trying to execute below code to fetch the JSON using Javascript,

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var obj

fetch(`url`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => obj = data)
    .then(() => console.log(obj))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

I am getting below as output:
`Object {Train_score: Object, Test_score: Object}`.

Please suggest why it is not showing the numerical value. I am executing my code using VSCode.

Comment: This may help you: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_debug-console-repl

Comment: Take a look at [GitHub issue - Terminal/Output panel print '[Object]' instead of value from level-3 on within json disturbing debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33174)

Comment: it's not longer JSON (string) it's an object - because `res.json()` parses JSON and resolves to an object - it's what it does

Comment: @Bravo, Thanks. I replaced res.json() with res.text() and I am getting required output now.

Answer (score 0):

This is is the expected output.
Just run node from the command line and you will get the same result.

> See [GitHub - Terminal/Output panel print '[Object]' instead of value from level-3 on within json disturbing debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/33174)

For seeing the whole object take a look at [VS Code - debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_debug-console-repl) from [@beniamin comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472482/json-is-showing-object-rather-than-numerical-value-in-output#comment103278283_58472482)